# Can't get config files when run ConfigServer and EurekaServer on docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

[Spring boot Microservies]

I have a microservices includes 2 services: ConfigService and DiscoveryService

- **ConfigService** is enabled ConfigServer, keep files config for microservice
- **DiscoveryService** is EurekaServer. It will get config file from ConfigService

When run 2 service on local (not docker), everything is good

```
Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8088
Located environment: name=epl-discovery-service, profiles=[default], label=null, version=3f6887b5b355381341e02ad03615f2415d6a566d, state=null
Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://github.com/stomer90/epl-config-server.git/epl-discovery-service.yml'}]}
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

but when run 2 service on 2 container (docker), ConfigService run normal, but DiscoveryService have **some error** (can not connect to ConfigService)

```
Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8088
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8088/epl-discovery-service/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

- **ConfigService**

EplConfigServiceApplication.java

> Blockquote

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class EplConfigServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EplConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
server:
  port: 8088

 spring:
  application:
    name: eplconfigserver

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/stomer90/epl-config-server.git
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

MAINTAINER Phong Nguyen

VOLUME /tmp

# Add Spring Boot app.jar to Container
ADD ./target/epl-config-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar " ]
```

*** DiscoveryService**

EplDiscoveryServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EplDiscoveryServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EplDiscoveryServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: epl-discovery-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8088
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

MAINTAINER Phong Nguyen

VOLUME /tmp

# Add Spring Boot app.jar to Container
ADD ./target/epl-discovery-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

- **Docker-compose.yml**

> ```
> version: '3.1'
>
> services:
>   epl-config-service:
>     build: ./epl-config-service
>     ports:
>       - "8088:8088"
>     restart:
>       unless-stopped
>
>
>   epl-discovery-service:
>     build: ./epl-discovery-service
>     ports:
>       - "8061:8061"
>     environment:
>       - REGISTRY_HOST=epl-config-service
>     depends_on:
>       - epl-config-service
>     restart:
>       unless-stopped
> ```

Link source code: https://github.com/stomer90/epl-spring-cloud-microservice

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

So you have correctly specified the order in which container needs to be started but this doesn't guarantee that previous container (in your case config server is healthy or not) since ur docker-compose version is 3.1 
you can define healthchecks in your compose file

eg:

```
 registry:
    build:
      context: ../service-registry
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: registry
    links:
      - configuration-server
    depends_on:
      configuration-server:
         condition: service_healthy
```

and

```
 configuration-server:
build:
  context: ../configuration-server
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: xyz/configuration-server
container_name: configuration-server
environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
  - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKER=kafka
  - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKER_PORT=9092
  - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZKNODE=zookeeper
  - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZKPORT=2181
depends_on:
  kafka:
    condition: service_healthy
  zookeeper:
    condition: service_healthy
healthcheck:
    test: "exit 0"
```

notice the healthcheck in config server which would be invoked from registry server (condition:service healthy)
you can implement your own custom healthcheck to something more sophesticated like

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
  interval: 1m30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 40s
```

refer this:https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

i guess that should be enough to kickstart your containers, let me know if it works